# Getting a lot a conflict while rebasing my branch with master

Tags: git, github, gitlab, bitbucket

While working on my branch i did a git pull - it's shows a merge commit in my branch commit history.

Now while rebasing master to my branch it's showing a lot of conflict almost every level of commit

Not sure if is it the right way  - i revert my merge commit and then do git rebase ?

or are there any other better solution to avoid messy conflicts

Comment: Certainly, if you're going to rebase, you should not merge first.

Comment: Now, why are you rebasing master to your branch? I hope you mean you're rebasing your branch onto master, because you should not be changing the history of master without a really, really good reason to do it!